# Parse Silent Push Notification not working if the device is unplugged

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm sending a notification using the parse REST API using the following payload to an iOS device running Parse 1.6.1:

```
 {"where": {"objectId":"XXXXXXX"},
        "data": {
          "alert": "ALERT HERE",
          "content-available": 1, "sound" :"",
          "badge": "Increment"
        }
      }
```

If my device is connected to my computer (plugged in) I'm able to read all the notifications and their payload through this code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
}
```

However, once I disconnect the device from my computer, the function is only called for the notification I swipe and not ALL notifications like I would except.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score -1):

Try this format including alert into aps dict:

```
{
    "aps" : {
         "where": {
                 "objectId":"XXXXXXX"
          },
        "content-available" : 1,
        "alert" : "",
        "badge": "Increment"
    }
}
```

Comment: The "aps" aspect is abstracted since I'm using the parse.com backend and it handles the notification aspect.